# Can not find Visual Studio GTK GUI designer/source button

Tags: c#, visual-studio, user-interface, gtk2

I can not find these two buttons. How to reactive those buttons? Thanks

**The buttons shows in red circle**
[image]

**Current Snapshot:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Find this answer:

1. Close the form code window (in the example above, close MainWindow.cs).
2. Re-open the code window--the buttons will now display.

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/70078/bug-report-source-designer-buttons-disappear-from-xamarin-forms-gtk-2-0-project